# Ansible - Working with block module

Tags: ansible

I'm starting out with Ansible and AWS.
I've created a playbook that launch new instance and later should attach existing volume to the new instance:

```
- name:                     launch instance
  ec2:
    key_name:               "{{ aws_vars.key_name }}"
    group:                  "{{ aws_vars.security_group }}"
    instance_type:          "{{ aws_vars.instance_type }}"
    image:                  "{{ aws_vars.image }}"
    region:                 "{{ aws_vars.region }}"
    wait:                   yes
    count:                  1
    instance_tags:          "{{ tags }}"
    monitoring:             yes
    vpc_subnet_id:          "{{ subnetid }}"
    assign_public_ip:       yes
  register:                 destination

- name:                     Attach volumes
  ec2_vol:
    device_name:            xvdf
    instance:               "{{ destination.instances[0].instance_id }}"
    region:                 "{{ aws_vars.region }}"
    tags:                   "{{ ec2_tags }}"
    id:                     "{{ volume_id }}"
    delete_on_termination:  yes
  with_items:               "{{ destination }}"
```

So far, so good, everything works.
I would like to add a clean-up method, so in case there will be an error of any type in the later modules, I won't have any garbage instances.
I've understood that the idea here will be to use [block](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#error-handling) module, however when I've tried working with block here, nothing really happens:

```
---
# EC2 Migrations.

- hosts:                      localhost,
  connection:                 local
  gather_facts:               no

  tasks:
  - name:                   Vars
    include_vars:
      dir:                  files
      name:                 aws_vars

  - name:                   Create instance
    block:
      - debug:
          msg:              "Launcing EC2"
        notify:
         - launch_instance
         - Cloudwatch
    rescue:
      - debug:
          msg:              "Rolling back"
        notify:             stop_instance


 handlers:
  - name:                 launch_instance
    ec2:
      key_name:           "{{ aws_vars.key_name }}"
      group:              "{{ aws_vars.security_group }}"
      instance_type:      "{{ aws_vars.instance_type }}"
      image:              "{{ aws_vars.image }}"
      region:             "{{ region }}"
      wait:               yes
      count:              1
      monitoring:         yes
      assign_public_ip:   yes
    register:             new_ec2
  - debug:                msg="{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id }}"

  - name:                 stop_instance
    ec2:
      instance_type:      "{{ aws_vars.instance_type }}"
      instance_ids:       "{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id  }}"
      state:              stopped

  - name:                 Cloudwatch
    ec2_metric_alarm:
      state:              present
      region:             "{{ aws_vars.region }}"
      name:               "{{ new_ec2.id }}-High-CPU"
      metric:             "CPUUtilization"
      namespace:          "AWS/EC2"
      statistic:          Average
      comparison:         ">="
      threshold:          "90.0"
      period:             300
      evaluation_periods: 3
      unit:               "Percent"
      description:        "Instance CPU is above 90%"
      dimensions:            "{'InstanceId': '{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id }}' }"
      alarm_actions:      "{{ aws_vars.sns_arn }}"
      ok_actions:         "{{ aws_vars.sns_arn }}"
    with_items:           "{{ new_ec2 }}"
```

Comment: Only the debug is working, it doesn't executes the handlers, so eventually, that's my question:
Why it doesn't executes the handlers under notify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `debug` task into the block. The `debug` module returns `ok` status, so:

1. it does not call a handler (this required `changed` status),

1.the `rescue`-section is never triggered (this requires `failed` status).

Thus it is expected that "*nothing really happens*".

---

You need to put your actual tasks into the block (I leave them intact, assuming they are correct):

```
- name: Create instance
  block:
    - name: launch_instance
      ec2:
        key_name:           "{{ aws_vars.key_name }}"
        group:              "{{ aws_vars.security_group }}"
        instance_type:      "{{ aws_vars.instance_type }}"
        image:              "{{ aws_vars.image }}"
        region:             "{{ region }}"
        wait:               yes
        count:              1
        monitoring:         yes
        assign_public_ip:   yes
      register:             new_ec2

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id }}"

    - name: Cloudwatch
      ec2_metric_alarm:
        state:              present
        region:             "{{ aws_vars.region }}"
        name:               "{{ new_ec2.id }}-High-CPU"
        metric:             "CPUUtilization"
        namespace:          "AWS/EC2"
        statistic:          Average
        comparison:         ">="
        threshold:          "90.0"
        period:             300
        evaluation_periods: 3
        unit:               "Percent"
        description:        "Instance CPU is above 90%"
        dimensions:            "{'InstanceId': '{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id }}' }"
        alarm_actions:      "{{ aws_vars.sns_arn }}"
        ok_actions:         "{{ aws_vars.sns_arn }}"
      with_items:           "{{ new_ec2 }}"

  rescue:
    - name: stop_instance
      ec2:
        instance_type:      "{{ aws_vars.instance_type }}"
        instance_ids:       "{{ new_ec2.instances[0].id  }}"
        state:              stopped
```